# How to make pages with a "template" controller and view in VoltRb

Tags: html, ruby, pagination, opalrb, voltrb

I'm having a problem in Volt where I need a bunch of pages with a "template" controller and view. Let me explain this in a little more detail:

Say, for example, I have a site about books. I have a page at `http://localhost:3000/books`. It serves as an index to other pages, e.g. `http://localhost:3000/books/fantasy/lord_of_the_rings`. I want all of the pages featuring books to have a single controller and view, so that I don't have to manually add in a controller and view for each book that I want to add. Rather, I just want to add in content to each page featuring a book to keep my workflow as DRY as possible.

So, the file structure under `app/main/views` would look like this:

```
views
├── books
│   ├── index.html
│   └── template.html
└── main
    ├── index.html
    └── main.html
```

And the file structure under `app/main/controllers` would look like this:

```
controllers
├── books_controller.rb
└── main_controller.rb
```

The problem is that I don't know how to set this up in `app/main/config/routes.rb` since I guess that's where pages' URLs are defined and their controllers, actions, etc. How do I go about achieving something like this in Volt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could for example use the following routes:

```
client '/books', controller: 'books', action: 'index'
client '/books/{{ genre }}/{{ title }}', controller: 'books', action: 'template'
```

This will route both requests to the books controller. And it will make the `genre` and `title` available via the params collection in the template controller action(s) and the view. You can then use this information to load the correct book from the store (or wherever).

You can read more about routes here: http://docs.voltframework.com/en/docs/routes_file.html

Comment: Yea, one thing to keep in mind is that order matters in routes.  They are matched top to bottom.